# Cross-Origin Request Blocked:http://api.fixer.io/latest

Tags: javascript, php

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: 
The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://api.fixer.io/latest. 
(Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' does not match 'http://winc-mypc').
can any one help to solve this issue

Comment: That's a valid log that you see. However you can use a chrome plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en But make sure, that the server you are trying to hit accepts `OPTIONS` call.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what kind of solution you're looking for!  If you just need to disable this feature in Chrome for development purposes, you can start Chrome with the `--disable-web-security` flag:

```
chromium-browser --disable-web-security
```

Answer (score 1):

finally i got solution using jquery,

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://api.fixer.io/latest',
    async:true,
    dataType : 'jsonp',   //you may use jsonp for cross origin request
    crossDomain:true,
    success: function(data, status, xhr) {
         alert(data)
    }
});
```

Comment: This will work only if the target API explicitly supports JSONP requests since it is a different form of response from the server.  And, usually if it supports JSONP, any modern API would support CORS so you could use that rather than the less efficient JSONP.